# single-tenant logic app how to set an Initial state for each workflow

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

In multi-tenant logic apps we can easily define in the arm template deploy the initial state of it easialy.

for example

```
"InitialState": {
  "value": "Disabled"
},
```

In the case of single-tenant logic app, there is a separation of concerns between the resource of the logic app and its workflows.

In my case, i created one single-tenant logic app manually in the portal.

And now the only thing i want is to do, is an automatic deploy of the workflows using azure devops pipelines.

In the `workflow.json` of each workflow i searched and didn't find a way to set the initial state of the workflow as disabled.

Does anyone know a way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a single-tenant or Standard Logic App instance you can set the state of a specific workflow by setting that state via a configuration setting in the app settings of the app service.

This app setting does require a specific structure though, see below snippet.

```
{
  name: 'Workflows.${workflowName}.FlowState'
  value: 'Disabled'
}
```

Updating a specific app setting in a web app can be done using PowerShell for example. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/set-azwebapp?view=azps-6.6.0).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If i go to the resource directly in configuration and create that setting it works! But yes, since i want to use a pipeline i will try with a powershell script

Comment: Btw, where could we get documentation about this?

Comment: I've uploaded a PowerShell-script which can be used to upsert an app setting in the app service, which you can find here: https://github.com/mbraekman/Powershell/blob/master/Azure/AppService-UpdateAppSetting.ps1

Comment: The documentation related to which app settings are supported can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/edit-app-settings-host-settings